# C++20 std::array implementation

Tags: c++, array, c++20

I'd like to have a review on my C-style array wrapper. I based this on std::array implementation. I hope you can leave some feedback!

### array.ixx

````
module;

#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <compare>

export module array;

export namespace stl
{
    template<class T, std::size_t N> struct array
    {
        using value_type            = T;
        using size_type             = std::size_t;
        using reference             = value_type&;
        using const_reference       = const value_type&;
        using pointer               = value_type*;
        using const_pointer         = const value_type*;
        using iterator              = value_type*;
        using const_iterator        = const value_type*;

        T _items[N ? N : 1];

        constexpr reference at(size_type pos);

        constexpr const_reference at(size_type pos) const;

        constexpr reference operator[](size_type pos);

        constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;

        constexpr reference front();

        constexpr const_reference front() const;

        constexpr reference back();

        constexpr const_reference back() const;

        constexpr pointer data() noexcept;

        constexpr const_pointer data() const noexcept;

        constexpr iterator begin() noexcept;

        constexpr iterator end() noexcept;

        constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept;

        constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept;

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool empty() const noexcept;

        constexpr size_type size() const noexcept;

        constexpr size_type max_size() const noexcept;

        constexpr void fill(value_type value);

        constexpr void swap(array& other) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_swappable_v<T>);
    };

    template<std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N> constexpr T& get(array<T, N>& a) noexcept;

    template<std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N> constexpr const T& get(const array<T, N>& a) noexcept;

    template<std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N> constexpr T&& get(array<T, N>&& a) noexcept;

    template<std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N> constexpr const T&& get(const array<T, N>&& a) noexcept;

    template<class T, std::size_t N> constexpr bool operator==(const array<T, N>& lhs, const array<T, N>& rhs);

    template<class T, std::size_t N> constexpr auto operator<=>(const array<T, N>& lhs, const array<T, N>& rhs);
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T& stl::array<T, N>::at(size_type pos)
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos, with bounds checking.
    *           If pos is not within the range of the container, an exception of type std::out_of_range is thrown.  
    *   
    *   @param: pos - position of the element to return.
    * 
    *   @return: Reference to the requested element.
    * 
    *   @excep: std::out_of_range if !(pos < size()).
    * 
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return !(pos < N) ? throw std::out_of_range("Out of range") : _items[pos];
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const T& stl::array<T, N>::at(size_type pos) const
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos, with bounds checking.
    *           If pos is not within the range of the container, an exception of type std::out_of_range is thrown.
    *
    *   @param: pos - position of the element to return.
    *
    *   @return: Reference to the requested element.
    *
    *   @excep: std::out_of_range if !(pos < size()).
    * 
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return !(pos < size()) ? throw std::out_of_range("Out of range") : _items[pos];
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T& stl::array<T, N>::operator[](size_type pos)
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.
    *
    *   @param: pos - position of the element to return.
    *
    *   @return: Reference to the requested element.
    * 
    *   @excep: None;
    * 
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return _items[pos];
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const T& stl::array<T, N>::operator[](size_type pos) const
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed.
    *
    *   @param: pos - position of the element to return.
    *
    *   @return: Reference to the requested element.
    * 
    *   @excep: None;
    * 
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return _items[pos];
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T& stl::array<T, N>::front()
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns a reference to the first element in the container.
    *           Calling front on an empty container is undefined.
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Reference to the first element.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return *_items;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const T& stl::array<T, N>::front() const
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns a reference to the first element in the container.
    *           Calling front on an empty container is undefined.
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Reference to the first element.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return *_items;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T& stl::array<T, N>::back()
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns a reference to the last element in the container.
    *           Calling back on an empty container causes undefined behavior.
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Reference to the last element.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return *(_items + N);
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const T& stl::array<T, N>::back() const
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns a reference to the last element in the container.
    *           Calling back on an empty container causes undefined behavior.
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Reference to the last element.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return *(_items + N);
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T* stl::array<T, N>::data() noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as element storage.
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Pointer to the underlying element storage. For non-empty containers, 
    *            the returned pointer compares equal to the address of the first element.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return _items;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const T* stl::array<T, N>::data() const noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as element storage.
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Pointer to the underlying element storage. For non-empty containers,
    *            the returned pointer compares equal to the address of the first element.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return _items;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T* stl::array<T, N>::begin() noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns an iterator to the first element of the array.
    *           If the array is empty, the returned iterator will be equal to end().
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Iterator to the first element.
    * 
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return _items;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T* stl::array<T, N>::end() noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the array.
    *           This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Iterator to the element following the last element.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return _items + N;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const T* stl::array<T, N>::begin() const noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns an iterator to the first element of the array.
    *           If the array is empty, the returned iterator will be equal to end().
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Iterator to the first element.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return _items;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const T* stl::array<T, N>::end() const noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the array.
    *           This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Iterator to the element following the last element.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return _items + N;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool stl::array<T, N>::empty() const noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Checks if the container has no elements, i.e. whether begin() == end().
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: true if the container is empty, false otherwise.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return begin() == end();
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t stl::array<T, N>::size() const noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns the number of elements in the container.
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: The number of elements in the container.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return N;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t stl::array<T, N>::max_size() const noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Returns the maximum number of elements the container is able to
    *           hold due to system or library implementation limitations.
    *
    *   @param: None.
    *
    *   @return: Maximum number of elements.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return N;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr void stl::array<T, N>::fill(value_type value)
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Assigns the given value value to all elements in the container.
    *
    *   @param: value - the value to assign to the elements
    *
    *   @return: None.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(n).
    */
    for (auto& i : _items)
    {
        i = value;
    }
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr void stl::array<T, N>::swap(array& other) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_swappable_v<T>)
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Exchanges the contents of the container with those of other.
    *
    *   @param: other - container to exchange the contents with
    *
    *   @return: None.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(n).
    */
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        std::swap(_items[i], other[i]);
    }
}

template<std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T& stl::get(array<T, N>& a) noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Extracts the Ith element element from the array.
    *           I must be an integer value in range [0, N).
    *
    *   @param: array - whose contents to extract
    *
    *   @return: A reference to the Ith element of a.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    static_assert(I < a.size());

    return a[I];
}

template<std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T&& stl::get(array<T, N>&& a) noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Extracts the Ith element element from the array.
    *           I must be an integer value in range [0, N).
    *
    *   @param: array - whose contents to extract
    *
    *   @return: A reference to the Ith element of a.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    static_assert(I < a.size());

    return a[I];
}

template<std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const T& stl::get(const array<T, N>& a) noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Extracts the Ith element element from the array.
    *           I must be an integer value in range [0, N).
    *
    *   @param: array - whose contents to extract
    *
    *   @return: A reference to the Ith element of a.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    static_assert(I < a.size());

    return a[I];
}

template<std::size_t I, class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const T&& stl::get(const array<T, N>&& a) noexcept
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Extracts the Ith element element from the array.
    *           I must be an integer value in range [0, N).
    *
    *   @param: array - whose contents to extract
    *
    *   @return: A reference to the Ith element of a.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    static_assert(I < a.size());

    return a[I];
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool stl::operator==(const array<T, N>& lhs, const array<T, N>& rhs)
{
    /**
    *   @brief: Checks if the contents of lhs and rhs are equal, that is, they have the same number of elements 
    *           and each element in lhs compares equal with the element in rhs at the same position.
    *
    *   @param: lhs, rhs - arrays whose contents to compare.
    *
    *   @return: true if the contents of the arrays are equal, false otherwise.
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(n).
    */
    std::equal(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin());
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto stl::operator<=>(const array<T, N>& lhs, const array<T, N>& rhs)
{
    /**
    *   @brief: The comparison is performed as if by calling std::lexicographical_compare_three_way on two arrays
    *           with a function object performing synthesized three-way comparison
    *
    *   @param: lhs, rhs - arrays whose contents to compare.
    *
    *   @return: lhs.size() <=> rhs.size().
    *
    *   @excep: None;
    *
    *   @complex: O(1).
    */
    return lhs.size() <=> rhs.size();
}
```
````

Comment: It's nice to see _someone_ using modules!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const T& stl::array<T, N>::back() const
{
    return *(_items + N);
}
```

**bug:** Shouldn't this be accessing element `(N - 1)`?

(Same issue with the non-const version).

---

Otherwise everything looks pretty good. It's just nitpicking below:

---

```
    T _items[N ? N : 1];
```

I think this works (allows zero-sized array with no compiler error, still ensures that `begin() == end()` because we use `N` to calculate them). But some comments to explain it would be nice.

---

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T& stl::array<T, N>::at(size_type pos)
{
    return !(pos < N) ? throw std::out_of_range("Out of range") : _items[pos];
}
```

Just style, but I think it's a bit clearer to put the `throw` outside of the `return` statement (we don't return anything if we throw).

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T& stl::array<T, N>::at(size_type pos)
{
    if (!(pos < N)) 
        throw std::out_of_range("Out of range");
    
    return _items[pos];
}
```

---

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr void stl::array<T, N>::swap(array& other) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_swappable_v<T>)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        std::swap(_items[i], other[i]);
    }
}
```

Could use the `size_type` typedef for the loop index.

There is an array version of `std::swap` which calls `std::swap_ranges` internally, so I think we can just do: `std::swap(_items, other._items)`.

---

Don't forget to implement reverse iterators!

---

If you want to go for completeness, there's also `make_array`, `to_array`, `tuple_size`, `tuple_element` and the deduction guide. [See cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: What do you mean by "deudction guide"? Anyway, thank you for the review!

Comment: The deduction guide lets users write something like: `std::array a{ 1, 2, 3, 4};` without directly specifying the type or size: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides

Comment: re `throw` inside the `return`: it could be legacy from an implementation that was written right after `constexpr` functions were added, when that was how you had to do it.  Like, 10 years ago.

Comment: `!(pos < N)` should *really* be written `pos >= N` for integral types. Complexity is bad. `T _items[N ? N : 1];` does not work for types which aren't trivially (or at least cheaply without side-effects) default-constructible for `N == 0`. `std::array<T, 0> x;` and `std::array<T, 0> x {};` must always be valid, side-effect free and dirt cheap.

Comment: All the mainstream implementations use specialization to resolve the issue mentioned by @Deduplicator: [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/array#L61), [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/array#L266), [Microsoft STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/array#L596).